# How to fix Browser Blue Screen of Death?

Tags: windows-xp, browser, bsod, safe-mode

I am running Windows XP SP3 and Firefox v3.6.2 and Internet Explorer and have an issue with Firefox and IE causing the Blue Screen of Death.  If I run in Windows safe mode, it does not occur, but running normally, it seems my firefox profile is going bad and results in certain web pages causing the BSOD.  IE is also getting BSOD on some pages.  For example, presently, if I visit ebay.com in Firefox, it gets BSOD.  It also fails when visiting http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en&source=iglk.  IT removed my Firefox profile and that seemed to fix the issue for a while.  However, now it has started occurring again.  I turned off all firefox extensions and it still occurs.  I'd like to fix my system so this does not occur.  The IT folks don't seem to be able to solve this, so I am trying to fix it on my own.  The BSOD is about something like (from memory) DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

Why would safe mode avoid the issue and what does that tell us about the probable cause?

I don't want to have to keep deleting my profile, so I'd like to find out the cause of the corruption.

Comment: firefox doesn't typically cause BSODs by itself (and especially not IRQL_NOT... crashes).  you are probably dealing with bad hardware (test with *memtest86+* on a Linux LiveCD such as Ubuntu).

Comment: There is not a good Windows XP memory test?

Comment: you can't fully test the hardware while booted into an OS, because the OS kernel takes up some of the memory and you can't test the areas the kernel uses.

Comment: really, if this computer is owned by the business, you should be getting your IT folks to give you a new computer, and let them repair/replace this one at their leisure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You will get [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for 'windows' too, but you still have to boot.
- You can also try [Prime95 or PrimeNet](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) without booting

Here is a reference page for [Windows XP Diagnostics](http://home.comcast.net/~SupportCD/DiagnoseXP.html) which has some other points too.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with corrupt WinSocks, so you may want to try [resetting the network stack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357). Also if you are getting network driver errors definitely try re-seating the network card, reinstalling the driver and/or replacing any network cables.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue!  My hint was that in safe mode (where it worked fine) the wireless network is not available combined with some posts I found on the Internet talking about nVidia and network.  So I looked into my wireless driver and found out that I was running Intel WiFi Link 5300 AGN driver version 12.4.4.5.  I then checked for newer versions and located v13.1.1.1 and downloaded it and installed it.

Since updating the wireless adapter driver, I've not had anymore BSODs!